# how can i search(.filter) in different languages?

Tags: ios, swift, filter, swiftui, searchbar

I get from the server an array of objects that have a name field in English.
There is localization, from the server I get an array of objects, they have a name field, there English always comes, and when I display I already do localization
in one case, for example name = Dog, if I write a Dog(language "ru") in the search, then nothing, if Dog then everything is ok
How can I do it correctly?

```
struct TypePet: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let image: URLString?
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(image, forKey: .image)
    }
    
}

struct TypesPetView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var languageSettings: UserLanguageSettings
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    @State private var searchTypePet: String = ""
    @Binding var listTypesPet: [TypePet]
    @Binding var typePet: TypePet
    
    private var filtredCount: Int {
        return listTypesPet.filter(
            { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchTypePet.lowercased()) || searchTypePet.isEmpty }
        ).count
    }
    
    init(listTypesPet: Binding<[TypePet]>, typePet: Binding<TypePet>) {
        self._listTypesPet = listTypesPet
        self._typePet = typePet
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
    
}

extension TypesPetView {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(Translation.typePet, bundle: languageSettings.bundle)
                    .font(.customFont(font: FontNames.notoSansRegular, size: 22))
                    .padding()
                SearchBar(searchText: $searchTypePet)
                Divider()
                List {
                    ForEach(listTypesPet.filter(
                            {
                                $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchTypePet.lowercased()) || searchTypePet.isEmpty
                            }
                    ), id: \.id) { type in
                            TypePetRow(typePet: type)
                                .environmentObject(self.languageSettings)
                            .gesture(
                                TapGesture()
                                    .onEnded {
                                        typePet = type
                                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                }
                            )
                        }
                }
                .listVisibleIndicator(isShow: false)
                .padding(.trailing, 10.0)
                .resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
            }
            .resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
            .padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
            Text(Translation.emptySearch, bundle: languageSettings.bundle)
                .frame(height: 48.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 44)
                .font(.customFont(font: FontNames.notoSansBold, size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(
                    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradients.capsuleCountCharactersGradient, startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 4)
                )
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .position(x: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2, y: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2)
                .isHidden(filtredCount > 0 ? true : false)
        }
    }
    
}

extension Translation {
    
    static var typePet: LocalizedStringKey {
        return "TypePet"
    }
    
    static var emptySearch: LocalizedStringKey {
        return "EmptySearch"
    }
    
}

struct TypePetRow: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var languageSettings: UserLanguageSettings
    
    var typePet: TypePet
    
}

extension TypePetRow {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                KFImage(typePet.image?.url)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 48.0, height: 48.0)
                Text(LocalizedStringKey(typePet.name), bundle: languageSettings.bundle)
                    .font(.customFont(font: FontNames.notoSansRegular, size: 16))
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color.white)
        }
    }
    
}

enum Language: String {
    
    case ru = "ru"
    case en = "en"
    
}

final class UserLanguageSettings {

    @Published var language: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.language.rawValue) ?? Language.ru.rawValue

    var bundle: Bundle? {
        guard let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj") else { return Bundle(path: "") }
        return Bundle(path: bundlePath)
    }
    
    func changeLanguage(language: Language) {
        let languageString = language.rawValue
        UserDefaults.standard.set(languageString, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.language.rawValue)
        self.language = languageString
    }
    
    func getCurrentLanguage() -> String {
        guard let currentLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.language.rawValue) else { return Language.ru.rawValue }
        return currentLanguage
    }
    
}

extension UserLanguageSettings: ObservableObject {
    
}
```

in the display (TypePetRow) works correctly for different languages, and the search is only in English, how to make it look locally in the language that is currently installed in the application (not in the system, localization is done in the application inside it and does not depend on the system language)
?

Comment: You can use [localizedstandardcontains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126767-localizedstandardcontains)

Comment: I tried it, it didn’t work, maybe I didn’t implement it correctly ... can I have an example specifically for my code? @LeoDabus

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you are asking questions you use [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Something that developers can just copy and paste and make work with little to no modifications.

See below for a possible solution. There is a lot missing from your code so I can't make it more specific.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LocalizedSearch: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    //Sample Objects
    @State var listTypesPet = [TypePet("dog"), TypePet("cat"), TypePet("snake")]
    @State var searchTypePet: String = "c"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            SearchBar(text: $searchTypePet)
            Divider()
            List {
                ForEach(listTypesPet.filter {
                    //Replace localizedName with localizedName(bundle:) if needed
                    searchTypePet.isEmpty ? true :
                        $0.localizedName(lang: locale.identifier).lowercased().contains(searchTypePet.lowercased())
                }
                , id: \.self) { pet in
                    TypePetRow(typePet: pet)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TypePetRow: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    var typePet: TypePet
    var body: some View {
        //Replace localizedName with localizedName(bundle:) if needed
        Text(typePet.localizedName(lang: locale.identifier))
    }
}

class TypePet: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var localizedNameSystem: String {
        get{
            //System language
            return NSLocalizedString(name, comment: "Pet.name")
        }
    }
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    ///If you want to customize in View
    ///Works with the System's locale
    func localizedName(bundle: Bundle) -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(name,  bundle: bundle, comment: "Pet.name")
    }
    ///Specific language resources
    func localizedName(lang:String) ->String {
        //Finds only the resources for the specific language
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        
        return NSLocalizedString(self.name, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}

struct LocalizedSearch_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LocalizedSearch()
            //Change the Environment's locale like this
            .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "en"))
        //This would be used in a parent view that references your user settings
        //LocalizedSearch().environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: usrSettings.language))
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

`Localizable.strings` for `en`

```
"cat" = "CAT";
"dog" = "DOG";
"snake" = "SNAKE";
```

`Localizable.strings` for `es`

```
"cat" = "GATO";
"dog" = "PERRO";
"snake" = "CULEBRA";
```

Comment: dont working, i switch language in app, search working only english
pasted the complete code from the project, no changes

Comment: Try using `@Environment(\.locale)` vs `UserDefaults` see above

Comment: Also, and probably obvious but make sure that all your pet names are listed in the `Localizable.strings` file in each language